# Beanshell script to use data from CSV

Tags: csv, jmeter, beanshell

I have dynamically created parameters using regular expression extractor and beanshell script (given below). I am creating parameters with `Name = "pass_" + i`.
Now I need to populate the value of these parameter field from a CSV file. I have loaded a CSV file and the login variable contains the value of the first row. The below code populates only the first value in the CSV file. I need the code to iterate through the CSV file and populate the parameter fields with next values present in the first column.

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("pass_matchNr"));
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) { //regex counts are 1 based
sampler.addArgument(vars.get("pass_" + i),vars.get("login"));}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using a [CSV data config object](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). You point to the path of your CSV and can then reference each CSV column in a Jmeter variable with ease. With each iteration, your Jmeter variable will hold the value of the next row in your CSV. From here you can use vars.get("yourVar"); to feed this Jmeter variable into your BeanShell script.

Alternatively, if you need the population from CSV to be done in one pass, an option could be to use the CSV data config object and set up your first column and row to be a concatenation of all the values found in the CSV for example 'ValueA,ValueB,ValueC'. You can then feed this variable into your Jmeter script and parse it in BeanShell by doing a split on (','). That'll leave you with all the values found in your CSV.

If these 2 options are unsuitable, a final option would be to create your own Java custom method which you can then feed into your BeanShell script. For example, you could create a class which reads your CSV file and returns a string in the format you desire. For a detailed step by step guide on setting up custom functions in Jmeter, refer to [this article.](https://www.capacitas.co.uk/blog/custom-java-beanshell-classes-and-methods-in-jmeter)